# ToBinding not working for Twilio rest call

Tags: rest, curl, twilio

I am trying to send an SMS message using Twilio via rest, using CURL.

Here is my command:

```
curl -X POST "https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS<My Private Value Here>/Notifications" --data-urlencode 'ToBinding={"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+18011234567"}' --data-urlencode 'Body=Test Message' -u 'AC1828d273602b76952c34368876b889a9:<My Token Here>'
```

Looks exactly like [this example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/sms?code-sample=code-send-sms-notification-to-a-number-2&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=default#).

But when I run it it I get this back:

```
{  
   "code":20001,
   "message":"Can not convert incoming parameters to Notification object: Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid",
   "more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20001",
   "status":400
}
```

The key part there is "`Parameter 'ToBinding' is invalid`".  But I have checked it letter by letter so many times.  It is exactly like the example.

**How can I make the above call work?**

NOTE:  I tried it first using "bindings" stored by Twilio.  This works just fine:

```
curl -X POST "https://notify.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS<My Private Value Here/Notifications" --data-urlencode 'Identity=00000001' --data-urlencode 'Body=Test Message' -u 'AC1828d273602b76952c34368876b889a9:<My Token Here>'
```

Comment: I think you should ask this to Twilio developers

Comment: I just went through the tutorial and it works fine for me. Did you create a binding like described here -> https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/sms?code-sample=code-create-a-binding-for-sms-2&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=default

Comment: @stefan judis - yes and it works if I use the precreated binding. It is the “ToBinding” clause that will take a phone number that does not work (that clause is supposed to let you skip the creation and storage of a binding. )